# Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, c++20

I am writing a piece of code for some students and I came up with the following implementation of Floyd's algorithm for finding cycles in linked lists.

I was wondering if there are ways I can improve what I have so far such that the result is

- more C++ idiomatic
- does not contain dumb mistakes associated with the generic code

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T val;
    Node* next;
    Node() = default;
    Node(T x)
        : val(x)
        , next(nullptr)
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>* detect_cycle_constant_time(Node<T>* head)
{
    Node<T> *n1, *n2;
    n1 = n2 = head;

    while (n1 && n2) {
        n1 = n1->next;
        n2 = n2->next;
        if (n2)
            n2 = n2->next;
        else
            break;

        if (n1 == n2)
            break;
    }

    // second phase of Floyds's algorithm
    if (n1 == n2) {
        n2 = head;
        while (n1 != n2) {
            n1 = n1->next;
            n2 = n2->next;
        }
        return n1;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## General

I found no "dumb mistakes associated with generic code". Good job.

Still, there are some points which can be improved.
(Aren't there always?)

---

The first point is encapsulation.

Letting nodes float around free, instead of keeping them in their dedicated container, or (rarely) evacuating them to a handle for re-insertion, is not recommended.

Admittedly, a properly written container won't suddenly sprout a cycle, so there you are.

Also, it would detract from the point of your code, so let's leave it alone *this time*.

## `Node`

`Node`'s default ctor won't initialize its members. The fix is easy:
Just add in-class initializers.

Doing so even allows you to simplify your second constructor, removing the second mem-initializer.

That is, if `Node` should even have anything but its data members. I personally prefer to have my `Node`'s not getting in the way when implementing my containers.

## Floyd's algorithm

The name `detect_cycle_constant_time()` is a bald-faced lie. The algorithm needs linear time in the number of nodes.

Doing an early return would simplify your code. As you don't allocate any resources, there goes the only argument against. Doing data-flow analysis is much more involved.

There are more loops than the humble `while`-loop. Sometimes, they are even useful.

Using `auto` would slightly simplify your local variable definitions.

Whether to use `class` or `typename` for template arguments is a matter of taste. All else being equal, I prefer brevity.

## Modified Code

```
template <class T>
struct Node {
    T val = T();
    Node* next = nullptr;
    Node() = default;
    Node(T x) : val(x) {}
};

template <class T>
Node<T>* detect_cycle_floyd(Node<T>* head)
{
    auto n1 = n2 = head;

    do {
        if (!n2)
            return n2;
        n1 = n1->next;
        n2 = n2->next;
        if (!n2)
            return n2;
        n2 = n2->next;
    } while (n1 != n2);

    // second phase of Floyds's algorithm
    for (n2 = head; n1 != n2; n2 = n2->next)
        n1 = n1->next;
    return n1;
}
```

Comment: `Still, there are some points which can be improved -> Aren't there always?` Love it

Comment: The name is pure (copy and paste like mistake) dumbness.

Comment: Would it be  good to also add support for non copy able and/or non default constructable types? For instance `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @DavideSpataro C&P gets to the best of us. As well as half-assed hasty and half-asleep rewrites. To support non-copyable, non default-constructible, expensive and other interesting types, *my* node-class is pretty much always a completely dumb sack of data. For various reasons, it is always composed of a links-struct (or single pointer) as the first member, and the payload as the second.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to everything mentioned in [Deduplicator's answer](/a/252246/75307): there's no good reason to force the caller to pass a pointer to a *modifiable* node, as we should only be reading.  I'd expect a signature more like

```
template <typename T>
Node<T> const* detect_cycle(Node<T> const* head);
```

I would have liked to have seen some unit tests for this code, to prove that the behaviour is as advertised!